# Publishing test results from Jenkins nightly build to QC

Tags: jenkins

Firstly let me say that i'm not that familiar with jenkins.
We currently have jenkins setup to run a nightly build set of QTP tests and collect the results.

My question is how do I export these results to QC? Please note: I do not wish to run the tests through jenkins, just export the results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what your question is, so I'll start with a suggestion and then you can clarify what you mean:

Make your tests generate jUnit test reports (if they already don't do that). Publish those reports with Jenkins *Publish JUnit test result report* post-build step. Then QC can view the results for any build via a link on the build page ('Test Result') or the latest successful build via the job page ('Latest Test Result').

You can also notify them via e-mail after every build that new results are available, and even provide them with a link to those results in that e-mail (that can be done via [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)).

Comment: Depending on what your test engine is, the [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) might be useful.